# Advice needed: Is it possible to change file path at certain time of day to display a different content?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web

I do have a question. Would it be possible to change a GIF file path (GIF is hosted on a CDN) at certain times of the day so that I can replace the first GIF with a different one?

Comment: you can either make the page detect the time of day and use a different gif or the server could run a cron job

Comment: Yes. Probably best to do client-side so user's timezone can be used. Likely will have to fetch the time at intervals and compare to your trigger time if you want the change to be dynamic and not only switched upon page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, simple just use JS Date object.
Gets the client local date.

```
<img id="img1" src="" />

<script>
var date = new Date();
var hour = date.getHours();

if(hour >=0 && hour < 12){
    //current hour is between 00 to 11:59pm
    document.getElementbyId("img1").src = "";    
}else{
//current hour is between 12pm to 23:59pm
    document.getElementbyId("img1").src = "";
}
</script>
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Another follow-up question, if I want the script to change the content from 7am to 6pm EST, then another change from 6pm to 3am and then one last change from 3am to 7am EST, should I add a new "if" statement? Note, that I am a complete noob with JS :S

Comment: Yes exactly just add another if statement and change the conditions to your needs.
Be notice this function is taking the user local time not EST.

Comment: Super dumb request, but could you tell me how to write the statement? I am confused with this atm: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: Hey! Sorry again for bothering you with this. I have another question, what if I want to add two more statements? Do I add them in the same format as the fiddle you sent above? @ItayTurgeman

Comment: What if one of those statements, is, for example, 9-9:30? I am getting an error with the ":" unfortunately